# Plotting boolean dataframes with a condition

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have two dataframes such as the following:

```
test1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[False, False, False, True], 'B':[False, False, True, False], 'C':[True, False, True, False]})
```

which produces:

```
      A       B      C
0   False   False   True
1   False   False   False
2   False   True    True
3   True    False   False
```

and

```
test2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[False, False, False, False], 'B':[True, False, True, False], 'C':[False, False, False, False]})
```

which produces:

```
      A      B        C
0   False   True    False
1   False   False   False
2   False   True    False
3   False   False   False
```

I want to plot these dataframes in a single plot in such a way that the y axis is the column names and x axis is the index. I would like to have a **yellow** dot wherever the corresponding value is `True`. If the corresponding value is `True` in both dataframes then I would like to have a **red** dot.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I make a graph: x-axis indicate a column index (`A`, `B` or `C`), y-axis indicate a row index. Is that what you want to do?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

test1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[False, False, False, True], 'B':[False, False, True, False], 'C':[True, False, True, False]})
test2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[False, False, False, False], 'B':[True, False, True, False], 'C':[False, False, False, False]})


# Make a matrix whose elements are 0 if both are True, 1 if neither True, else 2.
mat = np.vectorize( lambda a,b: 0 if a and b else 1 if a or b else 2)(test1,test2) 

y,x = np.where(mat==0)
plt.plot(x, y, 'ro')
y,x = np.where(mat==1)
plt.plot(x, y, 'yo')

xlabels = test1.columns

plt.ylim(-1,len(test1.index))
plt.xlim(-1,len(xlabels))

plt.xticks(range(len(xlabels)), xlabels)

plt.show()
```

Comment: @takoika
It would be nice if the bullets plotted changed in size (diameter) depending on HOW many correct matches you have.  For instance, when you got more 'true' & 'true'-patches this dot in the graph would be bigger. So you can not only see which values are corresponding yo either true or false, but also how many matches you have... Can you add that as well?